# Many-to-many relationship with compound primary key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I got a requirement for many-to-many relationship design in DBMS with other constraints.

There are two tables, `t1` and `t2` where `t1.id` and `t2.id` are primary keys respectively. `t1` and `t2` has many-to-many relationship, so a natural design is to add a third table `t3` with foreign keys. e.g.,

```
t3:
id
t1_id     (foreign key refereed to t1.id)
t2_id     (foreign key refereed to t2.id)
```

**Another requirement** is `pair(t1.id, t2.id)` should have **one-to-one** relationship with `t4.id`. Is it good to add `t5` with `primary_key(t1.id, t2.id)`? or we can directly using `t3's t1_id, t2_id` as compound primary key? We need to fast scan whether `pair(t1.id, t2.id)` has an entity in `t4`, i.e., `pair(t1.id, t2.id)` has one-to-one relationship with `t4.id`.

Appreciate if you could give me some hints.

Comment: It's not necessary to add `t5`. You could make `(t1_id,t2_id)` UNIQUE in `t3`. You could actually store the foreign key reference between `t3` and `t4` in `t3`. Just make `t4_id` fk column unique in `t3`. If you want to make the reference go the other way, you can store `t3_id` fk column in `t4` as well. It's valid to use a composite key as a foreign key, but for teams that use a pattern of a surrogate id column tend to like to keep with that pattern. One of the advantages of surrogate keys is that it avoids composite foreign keys for entity tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to enforce a one-to-one relationship between `(t1.id,t2.id)` and `t4.id`, that seems to indicate that `(t1.id,t2.id)` would be unique.

If that's the case, if `(t1.id,t2.id)` should be UNIQUE in <kbd>t3</kbd>, then you could make that the `PRIMARY KEY` for <kbd>t3</kbd>.

You could add a foreign key reference to <kbd>t4</kbd>, and make that UNIQUE so no more than one row in <kbd>t3</kbd> can be related to <kbd>t4</kbd>. Or, you can make the foreign key reference go the other way, and store the primary key values of <kbd>t3</kbd> in <kbd>t4</kbd>.

For example, to make the foreign key in <kbd>t3</kbd> to <kbd>t4</kbd>

```
 CREATE TABLE t3
 ( t1_id  INT NOT NULL       COMMENT 'pk, fk ref t1'
 , t2_id  INT NOT NULL       COMMENT 'pk, fk ref t2'
 , t4_id  INT                COMMENT 'fk ref t4'
 , PRIMARY KEY (t1_id,t2_id)
 , CONSTRAINT t3_ux2 UNIQUE KEY (t4_id)
 , CONSTRAINT fk_t3_t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1(id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 , CONSTRAINT fk_t3_t2 FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id)
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 , CONSTRAINT fk_t3_t4 FOREIGN KEY (t4_id) REFERENCES t4(id)
     ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ...
```

Or, you could introduce a surrogate primary key on <kbd>t3</kbd>. (We typically only do this if there are other tables that have a foreign key reference to <kbd>t3</kbd>; because now <kbd>t3</kbd> is acting more like an actual entity, than a pure relationship. And that avoids us having to use a composite key as a foreign key in another table to reference <kbd>t3</kbd>.

For example:

```
 CREATE TABLE t3
 ( id     INT NOT NULL       COMMENT 'pk'
 , t1_id  INT NOT NULL       COMMENT 'fk ref t1'
 , t2_id  INT NOT NULL       COMMENT 'fk ref t2'
 , PRIMARY KEY (t3_id)
 , CONSTRAINT t3_ux1 UNIQUE KEY (t1_id,t2_id)
 , CONSTRAINT fk_t3_t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1(id) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 , CONSTRAINT fk_t3_t2 FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id) 
     ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ...
```

You could add a foreign key in this table <kbd>t3</kbd> to reference to <kbd>t4</kbd>, as in the previous example.

Or you could implement the relationship from <kbd>t4</kbd> to reference <kbd>t3</kbd>.

Either way works.

My decision would be primarily based on

1) avoiding composite keys as foreign keys (if no entity tables have composite keys)

2) do we want or need `ON DELETE CASCADE` functionality, and which way does that need to work... a delete from <kbd>t3</kbd> should cascade deletes to  <kbd>t4</kbd>, or the other way around.

I showed `ON DELETE RESTRICT` in the example I gave adding `t4_id` fk column to <kbd>t3</kbd>. I figured that a delete from <kbd>t4</kbd> should probably not "break" the relationship between <kbd>t1</kbd> and <kbd>t2</kbd> by removing rows from <kbd>t3</kbd>.

Comment: great thanks for detailed explanation. I prefer to the suggested  surrogate primary key, because a further situation would be  (t1.id, t2.id) has many-to-many with t6.id, and so on.

Comment: @frocdcn: Before I make recommendations, I usually like to have more knowledge about the entities and relationships we're modeling for the business... "customer", "order", "shipment", "payment", etc. so I can ask reasonable questions, so we can come up with an Entity Relationship model that reflects what we need to represent. But... not knowing any of that, I'd go with the surrogate `id` primary key column on `t3`... if rows in `t3` have relationships to other entities. I'd also add the `id` PK if there were other attributes on `t3`, it it looked more like an entity.

Comment: I cant agree more that we are modelling for business. The core issue here is (t1.id, t2.id) has to be used as a single attribute. (t1.id, t2.id) has complex relationships with other tables, so that surrogate key would be easier for the whole business. Yet I have some doubts on performance compensation for surrogate key, because it has to iterate every tuple in t3 to look for a specific t1.id in t3. I think it is likely to get t1.id or t2.id from t3.id if we use some algorithm when composing t3.id, which will not be an auto-increment PK then.

Comment: Having appropriate indexes available will enable MySQL to perform the required searches optimally. JOIN operations can be remarkably efficient. I wouldn't worry about performance of "iterating every tuple in t3 for a specific t1.id in t3" (It won't be iterative, unless we hobble MySQL by making it iterative. If you're saying there's may be a performance advantage of storing `t1.id` in `t4`, and avoiding a join operation, that may be true in some cases. If you're concerned with lookup to get t3.id,  that may be true too. But with integer types and indexes, not likely to be a performance issue.

Comment: Do you have experience/suggestion of ORM mapping? such as Hibernate. I am new to ORM, so I'm not sure whether Hibernate can handle constant table change.